# Python YouTube API Retrieve List of Videos

Tags: python, json, youtube-api

I would like to fetch `all` videos from YouTube API for given `ChannelId` using Python. Below is the code I have tried, but I cannot figure out how to append the data in the `while` loop.

```
import requests
import json

mykey = 'myGoogleKey'
channelid = 'someRandomChannelId'

# First request
r = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&channelId="+channelid+"&order=date&key="+mykey)
json_data = r.json()
nextPageToken = json_data.get("nextPageToken")

# Retrieve all the rest of the pages
while nextPageToken:
    r = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&channelId="+channelid+"&order=date&key="+mykey+"&pageToken="+nextPageToken)
    json_data.append(r.json()) # this part needs to be modified/adjusted
    nextPageToken = json_data.get("nextPageToken")

with open('myJsonFile.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_data, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

print("All Done!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json_data.update(r.json())
```

Should do the trick.